# Delete duplicate label in GeoServer Style

Tags: qgis, geoserver, style

I created complex label style in QGIS 3.8.1 and saved it to SLD file then uploaded it in GeoServer 2.15 as a new style, but I should add centroid function to avoid duplicate labels, I tried to add it but unfortunately I got error message:

```
line 43: cvc-complex-type.2.4.a: Invalid content was found starting with element 'se:Geometry'. 
One of '{"http://www.opengis.net/se":Displacement, 
"http://www.opengis.net/se":PerpendicularOffset, 
"http://www.opengis.net/se":VendorOption}' is expected.
```

[image: error message]

Update:

[Download SLD file](https://mega.nz/#!spVlACjC!VdTq1gYRoGnUOBxJGVu42tgLX1Tz_zELFqtVFQUPTkA)

[image: Duplicate Labels]

But no duplicate labels, when i open the layer from "Layer preview" by open layer format.

Comment: Please place error messages in the body of the question as text. This makes it legible in all devices and searchable as well.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because didn't find a solution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While invalid that SLD will probably work as GeoServer's parser is relatively forgiving of errors of this type.

However, to fix it you need to place the `Geometry` tag at the start of the `Symbolizer` (the [manual](https://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/styling/sld/reference/textsymbolizer.html#syntax) gives the correct order for the tags in a `TextSymboliser`).

Comment: i tried many times but unfortunately, the same problem still exist, i uploaded SLD file to modify it https://mega.nz/#!spVlACjC!VdTq1gYRoGnUOBxJGVu42tgLX1Tz_zELFqtVFQUPTkA